# Qual a diferença entre papéis (roles) e grupos (groups)?

Tags: banco-de-dados, terminologia, permissões

Eses dois conceitos aparecem um aplicações, bancos de dados, sistemas operacionais e outros tipos onde tem várias pessoas acessando o sistema. É só um nome diferente para ames ma coisa? Ou então porque usar um ou outro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Um grupo é formado por pessoas, por usuários, ou mesmo só o nome de usuários. Eventualmente até pode ter um grupo dentro de outro. É uma forma de organizar muita gente ou manter uma coesão de como elas são organizadas no sistema que está usando.

Já o papel (*role*) é o que algum usuário pode fazer no sistema. Um usuário pode ter vários papéis. Um grupo pode ter um ou mais papéis, o que normalmente faria todos os seus usuários terem essas permissões. Um papel pode ser composto por vários papéis também, criando uma hierarquia.

Em alguns casos o que estou chamando aqui de papel pode ser chamado de "privilégios" (no plural mesmo), e aí o *role* pode ficar parecido com um grupo (ou até mesmo um usuário), ou é algo intermediário, então ele poderia ainda ser o que está definido acima, mas em vez de determinar cada privilégio individualmente para o papel é colocado um conjunto de privilégios previamente agrupados.

Claro que alguém pode usar de outra forma, mas isso é o mais comum.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).