# roles e permissions vs roles

Tags: node.js, typescript, express.js, arquitetura-de-software

Estou trabalhando com controle de acesso em node junto do express fazendo uma api e vi que em vários lugares é muito comum usarem roles e permissions para definir o que um usuário pode fazer dentro de um sistema, o que não consigo entender é: Para que é necessário usar as permissions ? não seria mais simples só verificar se o usuário tem uma determinada role e assim permitir que ele acesse um endpoint?

Exemplo: Um endpoint que serve para criar um usuário, Nesse exemplo tanto um administrador quanto um gerente podem criar um usuário. Se quem for acessar esse endpoint tiver uma dessas roles ele poderá criar um usuário.

Só com roles

```
employerRoutes.post(
  '/',
  isAuthenticated,
  is(['admin','gerente']),
  createController.handle
);
```

Acredito que é mais simples assim do que com as permissions. Para usa-las(permissions) temos que criar mais uma tabela no banco para atrela-la as roles, sendo assim mais trabalho.

Com permissions

```
employerRoutes.post(
  '/',
  isAuthenticated,
  hasPermission('create_user'),
  createController.handle
);
```

Só com roles

```
employerRoutes.post(
  '/',
  isAuthenticated,
  is(['admin','gerente']),
  createController.handle
);
```

Ambas não alcançam o objetivo desejado ? porque ter mais trabalho com as permissions ? Em qual momento é útil ter as permissions ?

Comment: relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/582538/qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-pap%c3%a9is-roles-e-grupos-groups/582539#582539

Comment: acredito que sua resposta não esclarece a minha pergunta.